# Get the id of all the <ul><li> dropdown buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got 3 dropdown buttons, named #select1, #select2 and #select3. These dropdowns are created like this:

```
<ul id="select1">
    <li id="s1">Text</li>
    <li id="s2">Text</li>
    <li id="s3">Text</li>
</ul>

<ul id="select2">
    <li id="s11">Text</li>
    <li id="s22">Text</li>
    <li id="s33">Text</li>
</ul>

<ul id="select3">
    <li id="s111">Text</li>
    <li id="s222">Text</li>
    <li id="s333">Text</li>
</ul>
```

It's pretty easy to get the id of the selected dropdown list item with $("#select1").on("click", "li", function() {}); But what I need is that when I click on #select2, i want jQuery to get the selected id of the previously selected dropdown as well. I've tried a couple of things, but have not come up to the desired solution yet.

Comment: simple use global variable to hold old value

Comment: @rajeshkakawat That I didn't think of that a couple of hours ago. Guess i'm a bit too new with jQuery. Thx :)

Comment: Or alternately, mark it with a class.